# Why does flex-direction: row-reverse start on the right side of the flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

By default, the flex direction along the main axis is ----> (left to right)

When you change the flex direction to row-reverse it becomes this <----- (right to left) but why does it start on the right side of the flex container?

Comment: Because that is what the spec. says should happen.

Comment: the spec is not always right. Ive broken the  "precise rules that govern the behavior of floats" a lot

Comment: the spec is always right because it's simply the spec. If you find something that break the spec, bring it here and we can show you that it's either a bug or a miss understanding of the spec

Comment: @TemaniAfif ok i will post examples later or tomorrow

Comment: It's unclear what you are really asking. It seems like you are asking what the word "reverse" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a normal behaviour when you mirror something.

If you want your flex-childs on the left side, you can do this witch `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
.flex-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### flex-direction

> It establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container.
>
> The main axis of a flex container is the primary axis along which flex items are laid out. Beware, it is not necessarily horizontal; it depends on the flex-direction property.
>
> The flex-direction property accepts 4 different values:
>
> - row (default): same as text direction
>
>   - row-reverse: opposite to text direction
>   - column: same as row but top to bottom
>   - column-reverse: same as row-reverse top to bottom
>
> Note that row and row-reverse are **affected by the directionality** of the flex container. **If its text direction is ltr, row represents the horizontal axis oriented from left to right**, and **row-reverse from right to left; if the direction is rtl, it's the opposite**.

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/)

I believe this last paragraph is what your asking about.